# Asihttprequest takes null values all the time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

i am working on a messaging app where all messages are stored in a server on temporary basis.
i have the follwoing code.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[BARAppDelegate returnsendmessageurl]];
ASIFormDataRequest  *request1 = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request1 setPostValue:usernameEmailid forKey:@"username"];
[request1 setPostValue:messagebody forKey:@"MessageBody"];
[request1 setPostValue:receipientnumber forKey:@"RecipientMobileNumber"];
[request1 setPostValue:sendermobilenumber forKey:@"SenderMobileNumber"];
[request1 addData:nil withFileName:@"ipodfile.jpg" andContentType:@"application/octet-stream" forKey:@"photos"];
[request1 setDelegate:self];
[request1 setPersistentConnectionTimeoutSeconds:30];
[request1 setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:YES];
[request1 startAsynchronous];
```

when i check the database on the server , surprisingly it has taken only null values for all the parameters(usernameEmailid ,messagebody,receipientnumber,sendermobilenumber). i NSLoged all those values just before the i put the request and they seem to be fine.

NOTE : this does not happen all the time. it happens few times . Also this happens only when i am trying to reply to an existing message that i have in the inbox. it does not happen when i try to send a new message.

am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using and asynchronous connection and to be able to know if something went wrong on your side or the server side you should implement the following methods before you call

```
[request1 startAsynchronous];
```

Add this:

```
    [request1 setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
    [request1 setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];
```

And implement this methods:

```
- (void)uploadRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{    
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];

    // Store incoming data into a string
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Server response:%@", response);
}

- (void)uploadRequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

     NSLog(@"[TWDEBUG] Error - upload failed: \"%@\"",[[request error] localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: i tried this, and did not find any change. the request sometimes takes null values and they are getting stored in the server. Any more ideas....

Comment: Since the problem apears after you reply to a message maybe you relese your values and assign them nil? Could that be possible? or maybe you did not connect your reply form in the IB and thus you get nil values when you ask for them.